# How do I wire up the correct Spring context to my Cucumber tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a working integration test for my Spring Web MVC app that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ShibaApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class EchoControllerTests {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    private void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void echo() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/echo/blargh"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("blargh"));
    }
}
```

Leaving that (successful) test in place, I tried to create an identical Cucumber test. The Cucumber runner is:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources",
                 glue={"co.masslab.shiba", "cucumber.api.spring"})
public class CucumberTests {
}
```

The class that defines the Cucumber steps looks like:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@Import(ShibaApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=CucumberTests.class)
public class WebStepDefs {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private ResultActions resultActions;

    @When("^the client calls the echo endpoint$")
    public void the_client_calls() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(webApplicationContext);
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        this.resultActions = mockMvc.perform(get("/echo/blargh"));
    }

    @Then("^the client receives a status code of 200$")
    public void the_client_receives_a_status_code() throws Exception {
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

However, the cucumber test fails, as the result is not a 200 but a 404.

I suspect this is because the WebApplicationContext getting autowired into the WebStepDefs class isn’t the same as the one that gets autowired into the EchoControllerTests. I’ve been going over the [Spring JavaConfig Reference Guide v1.0.0.M4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/), but I haven’t yet figured out where I’m going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept trying different combinations of annotations, and finally figured this one out. The annotations for WebStepsDef that worked for me were:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ShibaApplication.class, loader=SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@IntegrationTest
@WebAppConfiguration
```